# How find parent of teleported component in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

How can I tell if HTML element that was teleported to body was originnaly in specific component?

Component.vue:

```
<template>
<div class="parent">
    <p>This is parent</p>

    <teleport>
        <p>This is teleported content</p>
    </teleport>
</div>
</template>
```

Document:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="parent">
            <p>
                This is parent
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p class="teleported">This is teleported</p>
</body>
```

So now in my code I need to somehow detect that p.teleported is actually inside of Component.vue

What I'm trying to achieve is to detect clicks outside of such components. Existing solutions doesn't work because my components can be nested and teleported multiple times and I have to trace all of them.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to have a unique tracking for each teleport, you could use data-attribute and set a counter or something for it.

In case you only need to know the name of the parent, you could do set a common attribute or a classname to it.

Component.vue:

```
<template>
<div class="parent">
    <p>This is parent</p>

    <teleport to="body">
        <p :data-target=`parentName-${counter}`>This is teleported content</p>
    </teleport>
</div>
</template>
```

```
<template>
<div class="parent">
    <p>This is parent</p>

    <teleport to="body">
        <p data-target="parentName">This is teleported content</p>
        <!-- Or you could simply set a classname to it
        <p class="parentName">This is teleported content</p> -->
    </teleport>
</div>
</template>
```

Now you can access these by `document.querySelectorAll("[data-target]")`
and add `onclick` events to them in the file where you want the magic to happen.

Hope this could be helpful

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: Thank you! That is what I came up with as a temporary solution. Temporary because if I want to provide my v-click-outside directive as a Vue package, I shouldn't force users to do such things as manually set data attributes in order to get package working. This should be done by directive itself, but it seems impossible for now